# C# stored procedure with parameter for advanced search

Tags: c#, sql

Here is what i have so far

STP has some output and input parm
Here is what i have so far

STP has some output and input parm

Comment: We would need more requirements, but you should look at the `SqlDataReader`, an abundance of code exist for this.

Comment: Please don't use `select *`

Comment: What the procedure returns?

Comment: Can you describe the resultset you expect? One Row with many columns, many rows with one column, etc?

Answer (score 0):

While SqlDataReader can be used, it is a lot of code for such trivial task. With Linq2SQL and few clicks in designer You can write this

```
using (var ed = new MyDataContext())
{
    var result = ed.SEARCH_Information(ID, JobType, ImportType);
    //do whatever with the strongly typed result...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, You neeed call StoredProcedure. In this example You connect do database and call StoredProcedure with 3 parameters anr return DetailsDtoOBject
To call this try this:

Create class for return object

```
public class DetailsDto
{
  public string JobType {get;set;}
  public string ImportType {get;set;}
  public string Username {get;set;}
  public string Password {get;set;}
  public string Connection{get;set;}
  public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
  public string ContactPhone{get;set;}
  public string OldPassword{get;set;}
  public string Remarks{get;set;}
}
```

And this is a code for retrive the date form stored procedure

```
     using (var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;

            cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

            var id = cmd.CreateParameter();

            id.DbType = DbType.String;
            id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            id.ParameterName = "id";
            id.Value = yourTextBox.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(id);

            var jobtype = cmd.CreateParameter();

            jobtype.DbType = DbType.String;
            jobtype.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            jobtype.ParameterName = "jobtype";
            jobtype.Value = yourTextBoxWithJobType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(jobtype);

            var importType = cmd.CreateParameter();

            importType.DbType = DbType.String;
            importType.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            importType.ParameterName = "importType";
            importType.Value = yourComboBox.SelectedIthem;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(importType);


            sqlConnection1.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var result = new List<DetailsDto>();

            while (reader.Read())  // Each row from StoredProcedure
            {
                result.Add(new DetailsDto { 
                 JobType = reader.GetString(0),
                 ImportType = reader.GetString(1),
                 Username = reader.GetString(2),
                 Password = reader.GetString(3),
                 Connection = reader.GetString(4),
                 EmailAddress = reader.GetString(5),
                 ContactPhone = reader.GetString(6),
                 OldPassword = reader.GetString(7),
                 Remarks = reader.GetString(8)
                });
            }

            sqlConnection1.Close();
```

In `result` You have all rows form stored procedure. You must check is value from SP habe null value.

Comment: The SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlReader objects should be in `using` blocks to correctly dispose of the resources they utilise. Also your example would be better if it created some kind of object and populated the properties, which would sound more like what OP needs: repeatedly reading the first column of the resultset doesn't really make any sense, as you would only get the last value anyway.

Comment: Yes - You are right by for example for this man whitch is new in C# i propose to take a little steps

Comment: all seems good to me thank you . so if you see i updated your code for 5 values , 4 text box and 1 combobox , here is where i get confused how do i  get the result ? reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var result = new List<string>();

        while (reader.Read())  // Each row from StoredProcedure
        {
            result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

Comment: To get result You must tell my what stored procedure returs?

Comment: The stored procedure takes 3 input values ID,JobType,UserName and display all this fields : 
ID, JobType, ImportType,Username, Password, Connection,EmailAddress,ContactPhone,OldPassword,Remarks

Comment: @Goodeinstein Thank you ! tho, i keep getting this error " procedure or function [stp name]  has too many arguments specified"

Comment: @Kreon it is clear oo many "arguments specified"  write the name of procedure and all parameters

Comment: @Goodeinstein i have updated my question , and the Stored procedure is posted above  as well.